# SQL Server : find duplicates in a table based on values in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, duplicate-data

I have a SQL Server table with the following fields and sample data:

```
ID   employeename
1    Jane
2    Peter
3    David
4    Jane
5    Peter
6    Jane
```

The `ID` column has unique values for each row.

The `employeename` column has duplicates.

I want to be able to find duplicates based on the `employeename` column and list the `ID`s of the duplicates next to them separated by commas.

Output expected for above sample data:

```
employeename   IDs
Jane           1,4,6
Peter          2,5
```

There are other columns in the table that I do no want to consider for this query.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There must be at least 100 duplicates of this question (but I, too, am too lazy to search for them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select
 employeename,
 IDs = STUFF((SELECT ','+ CAST(e2.[ID] AS VARCHAR(10)) 
  FROM emp e2
  WHERE e2.employeename = e1.employeename
  For XML PATH('')
 ),1,1,'')
FROM emp e1
GROUP BY employeename having COUNT(*) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57e3b/5)

Comment: What about using CTE? "with CTE as (  select row_number() over(partition by employeename order by ID ) as rn from table )" - how to continue?

Comment: @HelenCraigman, not sure what you want to do with CTE that query show row number. for string concatenation, FOR XML is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Northwind example:

```
Use Northwind
GO

SELECT
   ord1.CustomerID,
   OrderIdList = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + convert(varchar(16) , OrderID) )
                           FROM [dbo].[Orders] ord2
                           WHERE ord1.CustomerID = ord2.CustomerID
                           ORDER BY 
                              CustomerID,
                              OrderID
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 3, 1000 )FROM [dbo].[Orders] ord1
GROUP BY CustomerID
```